# Run a shell script using cron

Tags: crontab

I have this `FeedIndexer.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh java -jar FeedIndexer.jar
```

Just to run FeedIndexer.jar which is in the same directory as the `.sh`, I would like to run it using crontab, so I did this:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user command
17 * * * * root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6 * * 7 root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6 1 * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
01 01 * * * root run-parts --report /home/slosada/workspace/FeedIndexer/target/FeedIndexer.sh
#
```

But I don't know how to run it. Have I made any mistake?

Comment: Probably should be on ServerFault.  But also, what do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Are you getting an error message?  Does nothing happen at all?

Comment: Are you sure you can put an instruction right after the sha-bang? http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html#MAGNUMREF says: This command interpreter then executes the commands in the script, starting at the top (the line following the sha-bang line)

Comment: No, my problem is that I don't know hoy to run it...

Comment: That's the third time you've said "I don't know how to run it". Run what? You don't run crontabs, the cron daemon parses them and runs the commands at whatever time period you specified

Comment: So, i don't have to do anything more??
but .jar is not being executed

Comment: Did you wait until 1:01 in the morning to find out? Your job is set to run every day at that time

Comment: @badloki6 - Why would this be better suited for SF? It is about crontab, which is fine here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `run-parts` part. `run-parts` is used to run every script in a certain directory, and you only need to run one script, which is handled by `cron` itself. So, this should work:

```
01 01 * * * root /home/slosada/workspace/FeedIndexer/target/FeedIndexer.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using single-digit hour and minute fields:

```
1 1 * * *
```

Comment: Ok, but how could it try it??
I mean, how would I run it??

Comment: You could replace each `01` with `1` and wait an hour, or adjust them to be `1 * * * *` to run the script on the first minute of each hour, for example. Here is a quick reference: http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you, that manual is really interesting about different possibilities, but i don't know yet what must i type in the terminal...

Comment: I am very confused. There is a crontab file under /etc/crontab. Just use an editor such as `vi` to edit it, and add your new line at the bottom.

Comment: that is what i did, but .jar is not being executed

Comment: The last comment from the OP was "this doesn't work", and now it's accepted. This is an extremely confusing question

Comment: Agreed. @Blanca - did you get this to work or not? Does the script work when you run it by itself? Is there any information in /var/log/messages about what may have failed with cron?

Comment: the problem is that FeedIndexer.jar is not executing, that is the meaning of 'doesn't work', sorry, my English is not perferct

Comment: No error information :s
and yes, the script works correctly, the problem is making with cron

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to wildly guess based on all the "it's not running!" that the job was intented to execute every hour, which is not what you wrote.

```
01 01 * * * root run-parts --report /home/slosada/workspace/FeedIndexer/target/FeedIndexer.sh
```

The minute and hour fields are both 1. That means when the current hour is 1 and the minute is 1, the job should run, which only happens at 1:01 in the morning. If you want the job to run every hour, do:

```
0 * * * * root run-parts --report /home/slosada/workspace/FeedIndexer/target/FeedIndexer.sh
```

This will run whenever the current minute is 0, which naturally happens every hour

Comment: @Blanca I edited my answer to show how to run every hour. As I said, your current solution runs daily, not hourly, which is probably why you think it "doesn't run" -- it does, just infrequently

Comment: I tried it every minute, just for test, and the .jar is still not executing

Comment: I would guess your cron daemon isn't running then

Comment: and what could I do?

Comment: @Blanca ...start it? I don't know which one you're using, but you can use `ps` to see if it's running; if not, start it